# Login persists across browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, forms-authentication, asp.net-4.0

Using Forms Authentication in ASP.Net MVC 3, it appears that the login cookie is cross-browser. When a user logs in in IE and then opens the site in Chrome, for example, they are already logged in. When they logout in Chrome and then refresh the page in IE, they have been logged out there as well.

Is this correct or am I moy loco?

How does this work? I didn't think browsers used a common cache for cookies.

Comment: They don't share cookies. Something else is going on. The logout can be explained in the way the server handles logouts though. If your server has a single cookie that is then invalidated all logins across all sessions will be invalidated making them all log in again.

Comment: If you post that as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Interestingly I just found out yesterday that Flash cookies can be cross browser on the same machine. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't share cookies. Something else is going on. The logout can be explained in the way the server handles logouts though. If your server has a single cookie that is then invalidated all logins across all sessions will be invalidated making them all log in again.

Comment: You're right, dumb overlook on my part! In this case I made a static variable instead of an instance variable.

Comment: ouch, I've hit that a few times myself :)